# services not parsed in heroku.yml

Tags: docker, heroku, docker-compose

I am attempting to convert my working docker-compose.yml to heroku.yml. My docker-compose.yml is as such:

```
services:
      api:
        build:
          context: .
          dockerfile: Dockerfile.api
        image: react-flask-app-api
      client:
        build:
          context: .
          dockerfile: Dockerfile.client
        image: react-flask-app-client
        ports:
          - "3000:3000"
```

When I attempt to run the same under heroku.yml then push to heroku main, I get:

```
remote: =!= There were problems parsing your heroku.yml. We've detected the following issues:
remote: 
remote: .services in body is a forbidden property
remote: Verifying deploy...
```

How do I convert the services to the heroku.yml file such that I can deploy on heroku?

Comment: Did you try to write the `heroku.yml`? Can you add it to the question?

Answer (score 1):

heroku.yml has a different syntax for the same things found on docker-compose.yml and it's restricted to produce only one image for production but allowing another image for the release phase.

Rather than defining Dockerfile.api and Dockerfile.client on heroku.yml manifest for a sole app you should deploy two apps at heroku with their own heroku.yml manifest on app's root path. Such as this.

```
#apps client
#api/heroku.yml
build:
  docker:
    web: Dockerfile.client
run:
  web: run_tasks_for_client.sh

#apps api
#client/heroku.yml
build:
  docker:
    web: Dockerfile.api
run:
  web: run_tasks_for_api.sh
```

Here's [a link explaining that](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/build-docker-images-heroku-yml).